# How to convert xml to DataTable?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a file with the content like xml, I want to parse it and bind data to Datatable. How can I do it ? My file xml look like this

```
    <StudentListSubject>
        <Member personId="1" active="yes">
          <Name id="Mary"/>
          <SubjectList>
                <Subjectvalue>Maths</Subjectvalue>
                <Subjectvalue>Literature</Subjectvalue>
          </SubjectList>
        </Member>
        <Member personId="2" active="yes">
          <Name id="John"/>
          <SubjectList>
                <Subjectvalue>Physics</Subjectvalue>
                <Subjectvalue>Maths</Subjectvalue>
                <Subjectvalue>Literature</Subjectvalue>
          </SubjectList>
        </Member>
    </StudentListSubject>
```

DataTable will 3 columns as below

```
PersonID#ID#Subject
1#Mary#Maths,Literature
2#John#Physics,Maths,Literature
```

I have used XmlReader to get data, but I don't know how to get id and subject list, only get person id.

```
        var _dt = new DataTable();
        _dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        _dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        _dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
        var _rd = XmlReader.Create("C:\\test.xml");
        _rd.ReadToFollowing("Member");
        do
        {
            var _str = "";
            _rd.MoveToFirstAttribute();
            _str += _rd.Value; //get personID
            _rd.ReadToFollowing("Name");
            _rd.MoveToFirstAttribute();
            _str += "#" + _rd.Value; //get ID

            ////get subject list

            _dt.Rows.Add(_str.Split('#'));
        } while (_rd.ReadToFollowing("Member"));
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you consider creating a class like `public class Person { public int PersonId {get; set;} public string  Name {get; set;} public List<string> Subjects  {get; set;} }` and then reading your XML into a `List<Person>` instead of a `DataTable`. It's only an opinion (and this is Stackoverflow-which detests opinions), but DataTables are rarely the right choice for almost anything in 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `XDocument.Parse` to prase the `xml File`. Remember to add this reference `using System.Xml.Linq`;

```
    string xml = File.ReadAllText("yourFile");

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("PersonID");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Subject");

    foreach (var member in doc.Descendants("Member"))
    {
        string personId = member.Attribute("personId").Value;
        string id = member.Element("Name").Attribute("id").Value;
        string subjects = string.Join(",", member.Descendants("Subjectvalue").Select(sv => sv.Value));

        dataTable.Rows.Add(personId, id, subjects);
    }
```

see this code: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A3u52f)

Comment: I got your point, but I don't know we can use with xmlReader ? I have updated my code above.

Comment: Btw, when I debug your code, it exit loop, nothing element, I confuse this line ```(var member in doc.Descendants("Member"))```

Comment: @Headshot see this link https://dotnetfiddle.net/A3u52f. This part of the code takes the `Member tag` that you can access to the internal nodes، and puts it in the `member variable`

Comment: @Headshot The `datatable is created and exits the loop`, you can print the datatable to the console

Comment: No, I mean when I debug, this line ```foreach (var member in doc.Descendants("Member"))``` will break , no loop and not get value. That's why Datatable notthing value.

Comment: @Headshot Instead of a file like the code given in the link, give a string. See, does it make a difference?

Comment: So, it's mean it parse from a string , not xml structure ?

Comment: @Headshot Did this method work correctly? If yes, check the file and the content of the file and see if it is read correctly

Comment: In your case, it is string data, but my case is xml content ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ``` with many blocks structure inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    XElement x = XElement.Parse(xml);
    JArray jArr = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x)).SelectToken("StudentListSubject.Member");

    DataTable dt = new JArray(jArr.Select(a => new JObject
    {
        ["PersonId"] = a["@personId"],
        ["ID"] = a["Name"]["@id"],
        ["Subject"] = string.Join(",", a["SubjectList"]["Subjectvalue"])
    }))
    .ToObject<DataTable>();
```

or

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    DataTable dt = new JArray(
    doc.Descendants("Member")
       .Select(a => new JObject
       {
           ["PersonId"] = a.Attribute("personId").Value,
           ["ID"] = a.Element("Name").Attribute("id").Value,
           ["Subject"] = string.Join(",", a.Descendants("Subjectvalue").Select(sv => sv.Value))
       }))
       .ToObject<DataTable>()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Function you can Use , According to your way you can Customize

```
    using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

public class XmlToDataTableConverter
{
    public static DataTable ConvertXmlToDataTable(string xmlFilePath)
    {
         
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            
            using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilePath))
            {
                
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataSet.ReadXml(xmlReader);
                if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    
                    dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
    
    string xmlFilePath = "data.xml";
    private Void ConvertToDataTable()
    {
DataTable dataTable = XmlToDataTableConverter.ConvertXmlToDataTable(xmlFilePath);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternate way

```
public DataTable CreateDataTableFromXML(string XmlFile)    
{  
  
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();    
    
    doc.Load(XmlFile);    
    
    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();    
    
    try    
    {    
        Dt.TableName = GetTableName(XmlFile);    
        XmlNode NodoEstructura = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast().ToList()[0];    
        
        foreach (XmlNode columna in NodoEstructura.ChildNodes)    
        {    
            Dt.Columns.Add(columna.Name, typeof(String));    
            
        }    
    
        XmlNode Filas = doc.DocumentElement;    
         
        foreach (XmlNode Fila in Filas.ChildNodes)    
        {    
            List<string> Valores = Fila.ChildNodes.Cast().ToList().Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();    
            Dt.Rows.Add(Valores.ToArray());    
            Progress();    
        }    
    }    
    catch (Exception ex)    
    {    
    
    }    
    return Dt;    
}
```